# Display total number of events in a category - Events Calendar Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm using [The Events Calendar](http://eventscalendar.com) Wordpress plugin and trying to display the total number of events in a category. Currently trying this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
            'field' => 'food',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And then using this to display the results:

```
<?php echo $query-> found_posts; ?>
```

My output is returning 0 though. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Looks like I had the first tax_query array properties a little off. Here's the fix:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => Tribe__Events__Main::TAXONOMY,
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'food'
        ),
    ),
);
```

Echoing the same query displayed the correct number of posts.